# dropbox save access tokens in db

Tags: php, android, dropbox, dropbox-api

i have developed an android and web-app.both these app uses drop-box library. in android app i get two access  tokens from the android drop-box library.. but in web-app in which i am using a php library i get only one one access token ... am i missing something ? because the problem which i having is i am sending two tokens which i am getting from android app to my webapp database so that i can use these tokens to access the dropbox from webapp without asking the user permission from webapp.. so i want to ask if some one has use the dropbox php library, how many tokens they get ? do they get two tokens or only one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing the OAuth credentials from DropBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741617/storing-the-oauth-credentials-from-dropbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only be receiving one token for each request; see the [Core API PHP documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php).

The general process is:

1. Get request token
2. Authorise the app using the request token
3. Get access token from the authorisation

So you should only be receiving one request token. I'd check to make sure that your Android app isn't requesting 2 tokens by mistake.

**Edit**: The above is correct with PHP authentication. However, with [Android](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android) and [Java](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java), you receive 2 parts to the access token - a key and a secret, much like a username and password. This means that you won't be able to use the Android access token in PHP.

Comment: then what about android? in android app i am getting two tokens ? what can i do now

Comment: @hellosheikh Answer updated - are you sure your Android app isn't requesting 2 tokens?

Comment: well i am sure // here is code in which i am getting two tokens pair ..one is key and other is secret   mDBApi.getSession().getAccessTokenPair().

Comment: @hellosheikh Sorry, yes that's correct - you receive 2 parts to the access token in Android and Java - a key and a secret, much like a username and password. You have to store both of these to re-authenticate. You won't be able to use the same token in PHP though because there is only 1 part to a Dropbox PHP token. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thankyou for your answer .. then can you suggest me the solution ..which is that if i allow from webapp it creates the duplicate folder ..one when allowing through the android and 2nd when allowing through the web app ? i want to use the folder which is created when user allows through mobile app first